# Deferred evaluation in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, deferred

I am following the example on page 107 of "Developing application with Objective-CAML".

```
type 'a v = Imm of 'a| Def of (unit -> 'a)
```

Now I am trying to understand how the constructor type `Def` enforces deferred evaluation? What does it mean to have `De`f parameterized with `(unit -> 'a)`?

Answer (score 4):

The type `unit -> 'a` represents a function. So the computation doesn't happen until you call the function. I.e., it's deferred.

The `unit` means that when you call the function you will pass `()` (a value of type `unit`, indeed the only value of the type).

the `'a` means the function returns a value of the type given by the parameter of the type constructor `v`. So `int v` is the type of a deferred computation returning an int. And so on.

**Update**

Here is a value of type `float v`:

```
let deferred_float = Def (fun () -> sin 1.0)
```

Note that `Def` is not a type. It's a unary value constructor (like Some). It's often useful to think of `Def` as a function that takes a value of type `unit -> 'a`) and returns a value of type `'a v`. Or you can think of it as a small tagged data structure that holds the function. In either case it's a value, not a type.

Here's how it looks in the toplevel:

```
# let deferred_float = Def (fun () -> sin 1.0);;
val deferred_float : float v = Def <fun>
```

If you imagine that it takes a long time (say a minute) to calculate `sin 1.0`, the point is that the value `deferred_float` is constructed more or less instantaneously. The computation of `sin 1.0` is deferred until you actully call the contained function.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. This answers my question.

Comment: A follow up question.
how would one then create a value of type Def ?

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question so it can be legible, and searchable by other people later on. Include any necessary definitions for people (like me) who don't have the book you're working with. In this code, for example, you're apparently using a record type that you haven't defined anywhere.

Comment: @IckyickyickyPtangzoopBoing If you feel this answer has answered your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left side of it. This helps others users see that it has a good answer, and avoids it taking attention away from questions that are still unanswered.